# how to pass id to the controller function through anchor tag in Cakephp2.8.5

Tags: cakephp

Hai everybody I am new to Cakephp. Thanks to everybody in advance. Please help me.
Actually I was trying to send id value from an anchor tag to the function inside the controller.

```
In my code I am passing id through `/users/home?id=<?php echo $alldatas[$s]['users']['id'];?>` where `users` is a controller and `home` is a method inside the controller. So i have written like that but when i am clicking the id i am getting the error as 

`Warning (2): Missing argument 1 for UsersController::home() [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 228]`

View page is index.php

    <td><a href="users/home?id=<?php echo $alldatas[$s]['users']['id'];?>" style="color:#1E6FAA; id='usid' "><?php echo $alldatas[$s]['users']['id'];?></a></td> 

Controller page is UsersController.php

    <?php
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    class UsersController extends AppController
    {


    public function home($id) 
     {

        //$allHome = $this->User->query("select * from users order by id desc"); 
        $allHome = $this->User->query("select * from users where id = $id");       
        $this->set('userDatas',$allHome);

     }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Your code is rather un-cakelike. - you shouldn't need to use query() here - Cake makes what you are trying to do very easy. Look at `Model::find('all')` and the conditions parameter.  [Read the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

Comment: Check if you have the correct view. If you are on `/Users/Home`, the viewfile that is rendered is `app/View/Users/home.ctp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this:

1. Action Params
2. Query String

> Action Params

// URL is /home/1

```
<?php

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function home($id) {
       debug($id); // this will return 1
    }
}
```

> Query String

// URL is /home?id=1

```
<?php

App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function home($id = null) {
       debug($this->request->query('id')); // this will return 1
    }
}
```

> [Cakephp Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters)

Comment: When I am passing id from anchor tag I am getting error like Warning (2): Missing argument 1 for UsersController::home() [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 228]

Comment: Either remove the `$id` parameter form the `home()` action method or add `home($id = null)` see my modified answer

Comment: Actually I want to pass that id to the Sql select query to get the particular record so id is very important. The warning error says that id don't have any value so how do I get the id value

Comment: In cakephp when your url is like `/[controllername]/[action]/[param]` e.g. `posts/view/1` you will get the value `1` in the action method as parameter  `view($id)`, here `$id` will have the value `1`, but as you are not using this format, and instead your URL is like `/home?id=1` the value is not available as a method parameter instead it is only accessible by `$this->request->query('id')`

Comment: Your answers through the comment what you have written /[controllername]/[action]/[param] e.g. posts/view/1  is very useful for me. Thank you very much